# Dynamically Import Vue Component Based On URL Params

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to import a vue component based on a path entered into url parameters.  So for instance, if `<host>/<path>` is entered into the browser, I want to import a vue component located at `<path>.vue`.

In my `routes.js` file, I have a route that will get nested paths:

```
  { path: 'object/:catchAll(.*)*', component: BaseObject }
```

And send it to `BaseObject`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="componentFile" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'BaseObject',
  data () {
    return {
      componentPath: '',
      address: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    importComponent (path) {
      return () => import(`./${path}.vue`)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    componentFile () {
      return this.importComponent(this.componentPath)
    }
  },
  created () {
    const params = this.$route.params.catchAll
    console.log(params)
    this.address = params.pop()
    this.componentPath = params.join('/')
  }
}
</script>
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/#/object/action`, I'm expecting the component located at `./action.vue` to be loaded.  But this doesn't happen - instead I get the following errors:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?9e79:38 [Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined) 
  at <Anonymous> 
  at <BaseObject onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <QPageContainer> 
  at <QLayout view="lHh Lpr lFf" > 
  at <MainLayout onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy {$i18n: {…}, $t: ƒ, …} > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './.vue'
        at app.js:416
```

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Why just don't import components in lazy way and then set them to `<component :is="" />` through `componentFile`?

Comment: @AriShojaei. how's that different from what I'm doing?  Maybe I don't understand you

Comment: You try to do it in a hard way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 problems with your code...

1. Your "catch all" route is defined as `{ path: 'object/:catchAll(.*)*', component: BaseObject }` so if you navigate to URL `http://localhost:8080/#/object/action` the "object" part is matched and `catchAll` param will be an array containing single item "action". So the `created` hook will pop this single item, `params` array remains empty and `componentPath` will be empty too (this is reason for `Cannot find module './.vue'` error)
2. In Vue 3, the old async component syntax (``` () => import(``./${path}.vue``) ```) [is deprecated](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#overview). You should always use `defineAsyncComponent` helper when creating async components (and this is reason for `Invalid VNode type: undefined` Vue warning)

So you `BaseObject` should look like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="componentFile" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "BaseObject",
  data() {
    return {
      componentPath: "",
      address: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    componentFile() {
      return defineAsyncComponent(() =>
        import(`../components/${this.componentPath}.vue`)
      );
    },
  },
  created() {
    const params = this.$route.params.catchAll;
    console.log(this.$route.params);
    // this.address = params.pop();
    this.componentPath = params.join("/");
  },
});
</script>
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamically-import-vue-component-based-on-url-params-3bzkn)

Also note that defining "catch all" route like this is dangerous as it will match all routes as - `/object/action`, `/object/action/dd`, `/object/action/dd/bb` etc. and those components will not exist. So maybe it would be better to allow only one level of nesting...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using Webpack to bundle your application and resolve JS modules. As you can see in the docs https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1, `import()` returns a promise, it works asynchronous. You have to resolve that promise first, before using the component.

```
methods: {
  async getComponentFile() {
    const component = await this.importComponent(this.componentPath);
    return component;
  }
},
```

Comment: I don't think computed properties can be async - my linter doesn't allow this to compile.  "error  Unexpected async function declaration in "componentFile" computed property  vue/no-async-in-computed-properties"

Comment: Valid point. Then maybe change it from computed to a method?

Comment: I tried it your way and I still get this error: `Component is missing template or render function`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard easy solutions!

```js
<component :is="componentFile" />
```

```js
export default {
 name: 'BaseObject',

 components: {
  firstComponent: () => import('...'),
  secondComponent: () => import('...'),
  thirdComponent: () => import('...')
 }

 computed: {
  componentFile () {
   return this.detectComponentBasedPath()
  }
 },

 methods: {
  detectComponentBasedPath () {
   ...
  }
 }
}
</script>
```